# Page loading issue. Apache + PHP + AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

I have a particularly slow loading web-page: https://uberdice.com/index.php

It's quite resource heavy so I expect some wait, but not as bad as this. The content of the page is a script I have bought and developed on. It seems the original developer added in the function below and I think that is what is slowing down the page significantly.

Once the page loads the cron works quietly in the background and is useful so I don't really want to get rid of it. I'm thinking that if I edited some sort of Timeout in apache then the page would appear quicker?

```
function imitateCRON() {
  $.ajax({'url': './content/ajax/getDeposits.php'});
  $.ajax({'url': './content/ajax/getDepositsrdd.php'});
  $.ajax({'url': './content/ajax/getDepositsbtc.php'});
}
```

You can see the diagnosis of the page here:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/d2D10z/https://uberdice.com/index.php

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to make it load quicker? Thanks.

**EDIT: I've commented all the cron stuff out and it's still taking ages. I guess I'm just going to have to try and find out what's causing it. Thanks for the help.**

Comment: The problem is not with that `imitateCron()` they are triggering and returning perfectly fine, the problem is with the initial load, so the problem is with some `php` or `sql queries` on the homepage/included files

Comment: Infact, i'm willing to bet (ha!) that it's the previous bets footer thats the problem.. comment out the php that generates that and see if the page loads quicker.. then if it does, look at what can be optimized

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ thanks for the advise and I've commented all that out, still no luck. Just going to have to try and find the piece of code taking ages.

Comment: Definitely concentrate on the server side parts, (if you look in your dev tools network tab, you'll see its the index.php script that is taking the time, not the JS files) - this indicates it's something server side taking up the time

Answer (score 0):

If you really think, it's because of the `imitateCron()` function, just comment it out/remove it and use a real cronjob. If you don't have possibility to create a native cronjob, you can create a cronjob on your computer which calls the urls or you use one of the http online cron services.